# How can I plot square wave data in R?

Tags: r

Consider the following data, where the left column represents a bit (1 or 0), and the right column represents the number of microseconds that we observe the bit.

```
0 664
1 63
0 404
1 544
0 651
1 686
0 507
1 1155
0 664
1 271
0 456
1 2763
0 664
1 115
0 456
1 4010
0 664
1 63
0 351
1 3855
```

I would like to plot this data  such that there is a horizontal line at 0 with a width of 664, followed by a rise to a horizontal line at 1 with a width of 63, followed by a fall to a horizontal line at 0 with a width of 404, and so on.

Is there an **efficient** and direct way to plot this in R that does not involve manual comparison against bounds?

Here is my current code for doing this which is extremely inefficient and naive, so I hope there is a better way.

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
data = read.table(args[1])
current = 1
sumA = 0

pf = function(x) {
    if (x < sumA) {
        return(data[current,1])
    }

    for (i in  current: length(data[,1])) {
        sumA <<- sumA + data[i,2]
        if (x < sumA) {
            current <<- i + 1
            return(data[i,1])
        }
    }
    return("OUT OF BOUNDS")
}
cumSum = colSums(data)[[2]]
print(cumSum - 1);


h = Vectorize(pf)
plot(h, 1, cumSum-1, n=cumSum-1, lwd=0.001, xlim=c(0,cumSum-1))
```

Comment: The [`plot` command with `type` flag set to `s` or `S`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) should be of interest of you. _"The two step types differ in their x-y preference: Going from (x1,y1) to (x2,y2) with x1 < x2, type = "s" moves first horizontal, then vertical, whereas type = "S" moves the other way around."_

Comment: @dfri, I will look into that. Thanks!

Comment: @dfri, Why did you delete your answer? I was about to try it out.

Comment: @jenesaisquoi, Your comment also looked interesting if different than dfri's approach. You should post that as an answer also.

Comment: @merlin2011 I did a mistake(-shift) of your data in my answer, corrected and undeleted now.

Comment: @dfri, No worries. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, [`plot` command](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/plot.html) with `type` flag set to `s` should do the trick.

E.g., for you first `10` samples:

```
x <- c(0,664,63,404,544,651,686,507,1155,664,271)
xC <- cumsum(x)
y <- c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
plot(xC,y,type='s')
```

[image]